# NotSupportedException while executing to inserts in EF Core 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ef-core-8.0

I have a problem with EF Core 8, with two insert operations in one method. I try to add a new record to first table, next step is get data from another table, and insert third data to third table, which is related to first table.

Code below:

```
_context.Table1.Add(table1obj);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

var path = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<Table2Dto>($$"""
        SELECT...
    """)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

var table3obj = path.ConvertAll(x => new Table3
{
    Name = x.Name,
    OrderNumber = x.OrderNumber,
    Table1RefId = x.Id
});

_context.Table3.AddRange(table3obj);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

'SqlQuery()' and 'Add()' for Table1 works properly, but for Table3 it shows:
`System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.`

Full text error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException()
   at System.Linq.EmptyPartition`1.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TElement>.Add(TElement item)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor`3.AddStandalone(Object collection, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor`3.Add(Object entity, Object value, Boolean forMaterialization)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.AddToCollection(INavigationBase navigationBase, Object value, Boolean forMaterialization)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.AddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.SetReferenceOrAddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.ToDependentFixup(InternalEntityEntry dependentEntry, InternalEntityEntry principalEntry, IForeignKey foreignKey, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.InitialFixup(InternalEntityEntry entry, InternalEntityEntry duplicateEntry, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.StateChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState oldState, Boolean fromQuery)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.FireStateChanged(EntityState oldState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityStates(IEnumerable`1 entities, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)
   at WebSTapp.Server.Repositories.Activities.ActivityRepository.AddPathToActivity(ActivityAssignment asss, String activityId, String dataAreaId, Int32 assignmentId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\sources\WebST\WebST-v2\WebSTapp\Server\Repositories\Activities\ActivityRepository.cs:line 660
   at WebSTapp.Server.Services.Activities.ActivityService.CreateActivitiesAssignment(ActivitiesAssignmentRequest activitiesAssignmentDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\sources\WebST\WebST-v2\WebSTapp\Server\Services\Activities\ActivityService.cs:line 263
   at WebSTapp.Server.Controllers.AssignmentsController.CreateAssignement(ActivitiesAssignmentRequest activitiesAssignmentDto) in D:\sources\WebST\WebST-v2\WebSTapp\Server\Controllers\AssignmentsController.cs:line 65
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|7_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails.ProblemDetailsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: EF Core has no `SqlQuery` method. Where did this come from? What's the *real* query and the actual full exception text? The rest code itself has serious issues - `SaveChanges` persists *all* pending changes. There's no reason at all to call it twice. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection and deals with entities, not tables. If you `Add()` a root object all *related* objects will get attached in the `Added` state as well.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, it does - [`RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.SqlQuery<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.sqlquery?view=efcore-8.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-relationaldatabasefacadeextensions-sqlquery-1(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-infrastructure-databasefacade-system-formattablestring))

Comment: Please add the full error text.

Comment: I missed that one, and I remember LINQ-to-SQL had a similar method. We still have no idea what isn't supported or what any of those objects are. Or even what throws - `AddRange` is used on `Table3`, not `Table2`.

Comment: @GuruStron I have updated a description with full text error.

Comment: I don't think so if this problem is related to`SqlQuery` method. I commented query and hardcode an example data and a problem still persist.

Comment: The error is related to the code and the bad practices shown even in this incomplete code. You don't work with tables. You don't have to save objects in a specific order. If you want to save an activity with multiple assignments, create the plain old C# objects, and just call `Add` in the root object. After that `SaveChanges` will persist all of them in the correct order.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't fix this issue, but i workaround it. I split this method on 2 methods in 2 different repositories. One method adds data to Table1 and second method adds data to Table3, and it works!

But I won't give up and I'll still looking for a problem.

**EDIT**:
Another workaround:

Let EF core to add a list by adding it to main tables collection.

```
var path = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<Table2Dto>($$"""
        SELECT...
    """)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

var table3obj = path.ConvertAll(x => new Table3
{
    Name = x.Name,
    OrderNumber = x.OrderNumber,
    Table1RefId = x.Id
});

table1obj.table3objList = table3obj;
_context.Table1.Add(table1obj);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: You still haven't posted the real code and the entities. The "repositories" you used are almost certainly the *cause* of the problem. EF neither has nor needs any "repositories", it's a higher-level abstraction dealing with *entities*, not tables. You don't need to split anything or even save entities separately. `SaveChanges` will persist *all* pending changes, to all the objects it tracks, at once. Just by calling `SaveChanges` twice you introduced a critical bug that breaks concurrency.

Comment: To put it another way, you can't be the only EF developer who can't save related objects like the Blog and Posts shown in the documentation. This means you're doing something wrong. If you want to create an activity with multiple assignments, *all* you have to do is create the new Activity object in memory, add assignments to its `Activity.Assingments` property and then *only call context.Add(activity)* to start tracking *all* the new objects in the `Added` state. After that, `SaveChanges` would save *all* of them at once.